# float, stream and toolchain

Tags: archlinux, hard-float

I'm working with a raspberry 2 running Arch

```
Linux a4h-rpi2-arch 4.1.12-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 27 19:16:16 MDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I got some problem to display float on cout using c++ streams. Here is a simple main :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main() {

float f;
f = 9.87654321f;
cout << f << endl;
f = 987.654321f;
cout << f << endl;
f = 987654.321f;
cout << f << endl;
f = 9876543.21f;
cout << f << endl;
f = 0.0000987654321f;
cout << f << endl;
return 0;
}
```

i cross compiled it with raspberry toolchain :

```
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o /tmp/test_stream /tmp/test.cpp
```

Here is result :

```
test_stream
0
0
0
0
0
```

Now if I compile it with

```
arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o /tmp/test_stream /tmp/test.cpp
```

I get correct results :

```
test_stream
9.87654
987.654
987654
9.87654e+06
9.87654e-05
```

In first case I'm only using software to perform float calculations. 
I shouldn't have any differences in result between 2 toolchain? Only compute time should be better using hard float hw unit?

lah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In first case I'm only using software to perform float calculations.

No; since the executable is dynamically linked to the system library on a platform with hardware floating point support, there is no facility to perform such calculations with software.

At least, that's my guess. I think it will turn out differently if you compile a static binary.

Put another way, this:

```
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

Is evidently the wrong compiler for the platform.

Comment: Just for testing I compiled it statically and I got correct results. So I changed toolchain.